# Set position of element based on SVG path location

Tags: jquery, svg

#### Question: How would you position `#info-box` based on which path is hovered

#### Issue: User is not able to hover into the `#info-box`

Currently I have the info box being positioned based on mouse location. This doesn't allow them to click into any links that are in the box. I'm hoping to have a review of how I am positioning my info box element. What would you change?

I'm not able to provide a code sample on stackoverflow because of the svg def exceeding the character limit. Here is my codepen.
https://codepen.io/lukeshinn/pen/aPQZJV

Comment: You could just leave the `#info-box` where it appears for them, and detect whether it's been shown already for the hovered state. If it hasn't, then show it, if it's already shown for that item, do nothing. Yes, the box will be there permanently after you hover over one location, but you'll be able to easily hover over a location, then click the links in the box. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/roPYbj

Comment: Have you considered to show the info-box on click, and add an element to close the info-box?

Comment: Thanks enxaneta; great solution. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pointer-events` css property to make the info-box insensitive to hover but its anchor child clickable:

```css
#info-box {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#info-box a {
  pointer-events: click;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by changing the `mouseover` event listener to `click` also added a span element to close the `#info-box` instead of it closing when you hover off the path.

```
  $('#info-box').css('display','block');
  $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-30);
  $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
});
```